# Tee/sed/systemd-cat delaying messages to journald

Tags: debugging, sed, tee, journal

I need a script to send stdout to journald and to the console parallel. For the journald lines I need to sanitize the messages before persisting.

I have a dummy example to show my issue:

```
ping google.com | tee >( sed 's/seq/SEQ/' | systemd-cat -t 'my-ping')
```

When I have sed & systemd-cat the messages to journald are delayed and they arrive only after stopping the ping process.

Example:

```
$ ping google.com | tee >( sed 's/seq/SEQ/' | systemd-cat -t 'my-ping')
PING google.com (216.58.197.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=40 time=240 ms
64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=40 time=240 ms
64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=40 time=240 ms
64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=40 time=240 ms
64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_seq=5 ttl=40 time=240 ms
^C
```

The messages are going in all at once (see timestamp):

```
journalctl -f | grep my-ping
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: PING google.com (216.58.197.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: 64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_SEQ=1 ttl=40 time=240 ms
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: 64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_SEQ=2 ttl=40 time=240 ms
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: 64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_SEQ=3 ttl=40 time=240 ms
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: 64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_SEQ=4 ttl=40 time=240 ms
Aug 17 06:03:40 hostname my-ping[30555]: 64 bytes from nrt13s49-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.238): icmp_SEQ=5 ttl=40 time=240 ms
```

It seems this behavior only presents when I use both if any one of them is left out everything works as expected.

Do you have any pointers what can be the issue and how to get over it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I don't think that this is a buffer issue. I tried the answers here but they didn't help.